# Different formats of timestamps on converting strings to Timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Why do I get different formats of timestamps on converting these two strings to Timestamp type in Python?

```
pd.to_datetime('05/09/2017 17:10')
>>>>Timestamp('2017-05-09 17:10:00')

pd.to_datetime('29/09/2017 17:10')
>>>>Timestamp('2017-09-29 17:10:00')
```

I have also tried

```
 pd.to_datetime('29/09/2017 17:10', format = "%d%m%Y")
```

to which I get

```
ValueError: time data '29/09/2017 17:10' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)
```

I would like to get my timestamps in Timestamp('2017-05-09 17:10:00') format.

Comment: You have to clarify what do you mean by `05-09`: day-month or month-day? That's the reason why `to_datetime` returns different results. In the 2nd case you clearly have a day-month format

Comment: 05-09 is in day-moth format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the forward slashes as well as the hour and minute in the format spec string. The format string should be `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('29/09/2017 17:10', format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
Timestamp('2017-09-29 17:10:00')

>>> pd.to_datetime('05/09/2017 17:10', format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
Timestamp('2017-09-05 17:10:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module may be useful for you.

From the site:

> dateparser provides modules to easily parse localized dates in almost any string formats commonly found on web pages.